# Wick doesn't triggered signal of crossunder or crossover

Tags: pine-script

I have an issue with an indicator.

I am “shapeploting” crossovers and crossunders. Signal should be triggered if the equal if body or wick is crossing the daily high or low.

As you can see in the following example :
[image: Example]

Signal should be triggered when the body of the bullish candle is crossing the daily high and when the wick of the bullish candle is crossing the daily low, which doesn’t happen for a reason I don’t understand. We can see in the second example above that the signal is only triggered when the body cross the daily low…

Here’s the code :

```
longPoint  = dailyHigh + (entryPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick)
ShortPoint = dailyLow - (entryPips * 10 * syminfo.mintick)

buy     = ta.crossover(high,longPoint)
sell    = ta.crossunder(low,ShortPoint)

plotshape(delayElapsed and (showOnlyFirstSignal ? buy and not buy[1] : buy), title='Long Entry', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(delayElapsed and (showOnlyFirstSignal ? sell and not sell[1] : sell), title='Short Entry', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
```

Basically, would need the signal triggered one time a day, when daily high or daily low is crossed for the first time(equal if daily high or daily low).

Would appreciate your expertise.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `delayElapsed` and `showOnlyFirstSignal` variables and how do you define them?? Share a compilable code example that can be replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try previous value of the line
Something like this:

```
buy     = ta.crossover(high,longPoint[1])
sell    = ta.crossunder(low,ShortPoint[1])
```